# Can there be an Underwater Advanced Civilization?

Tags: culture, engineering, civilization, science-in-society, scientific-development

After watching Aquaman and, most recently, Black Panther: Wakanda Forever, which features Namor and his underwater empire, I got curious about the feasibility of an underwater civilization composed of human-like beings and how advanced could they become being limited to be underwater versus being amphibian and having access to dry spaces and the surface.

Assuming they are adapted to the pressure/darkness issues, could they ever become as advanced as the modern "surface" world? Or there are things that they could never do?

(Without relying on magic of course, because obviously anything is possible with magic.)

EDIT:

Some problems from the original question I need to address:

-By "human-like" I mean generally humanoid and with the same level of cognition as humans (how they came to this level of cognition being restrained to underwater is mostly irrelevant to me but if you could share some thoughts about it would be interesting.)

-These creatures arised to this level of cognition while still living underwater and their biology is perfectly adapted to this environment, the question is about their limitations on technological development without having amphibious capabilities and being stuck to working on submerged spaces with whatever natural resources they have available, they can pump water out of containers, for example, they just can't breath out of water.

Thanks for all the answers so far.

Comment: This question is underconstrained, so I don't think it can be usefully answered in its current form. There are a lot of other questions on this site about underwater technology, but the critical issue to my mind is fire from which so much other human technology flows. Without something to replace glass, metal and ceramics they're like to be quite limited. As the author, you can handwave in anything you like as a replacement, of course ("biotech" is the easiest excuse).

Comment: If we were capable of generating an entire underwater tech tree accurately, we wouldn't be on stack exchange, we would be earning billions.

Comment: As Starfish Prime mentions, we need more information, most of all, I think, what or who these "human-like beings" are, how they 'currently' live, &c.

Comment: *"Human-like beings"* cannot live underwater, and, in general, cannot spend  too much time in water. Our skin is not waterproof and is completely destroyed after two or three days of immersion in water. Our bodies cannot retain heat if immersed in water, so that even in the tropics we would die of exposure. Our limbs are not good at all for moving underwater. Etc. Human-like beings are great apes adapted to life in the hot savannah of Africa; look at a seal to see how an aquatic mammal looks like.

Comment: The "human like beings" requirement prevents a positive answer. If you were to let that go you could start considering what an "advanced civilization" is. Is it one that necessarily have lots of tools. How about family groups? traditions? songs? How about our whales? How much better humans and whales would fare if they were to understand one another more?

Answer (score 3):

**Fire and Steel**

[image]

The first great inventions of humanity were cooking food, pottery, the wheel, and metalworking. Ask me to put them in order and I will hum and haw all day. But they are all certainly in my personal top ten!

Three of the Big Four rely on fire. Since you cannot start a fire underwater, your civilization is stuck in the stone age.  But the Stone age is not without its benefits.

[image]

Comment: I think the possibilities are much greater than that. Limiting to just how humans progressed is a strange restriction. I don't doubt they can invent underwater agriculture or ways to store food. Moving things long distances without the wheel seems easier inside the water as well. There is plenty of opportunities to progress under water without metal working.

Comment: @Trioxidane It is hard to measure "how advanced" they are if they advanced in a perpendicular way to us land apes. Certainly there are "things that they could never do"

Answer (score 2):

**Unlikely**

At least as far as our current knowledge goes. One could easily imagine neolithic underwater tribes with their stone/shell/coral/bone tools and structures, but advancing any further than that would require metalworking which is going to be tricky if not outright impossible for them to do underwater. Being amphibious will help greatly with this, as they may then be able to go on land to make fires and do all the neat things with heat that we can do, but odds are they're going to phase out of being primarily water-based and evolve into a more land-based species if they stick to using fire to improve their lives.

There is another way they could develop and advance, biotech, where they use all kinds of living creatures and organic processes to do things, though such a purely biological tech tree leading up to a 'modern' era is mostly theoretical, as while we do have biological engines that we've used to haul things and put work energy into mechanical devices(animal/slave + cart/mill), and while we do have biological food producing machines that extract nutrients and energy from the environment for us to harvest and consume(farms/crops), adapting biological structures into doing other things will involve an extreme amount of research and selective breeding to get anywhere remotely viable as far as biological analogues to technological advancements go and will slow down the progress of any civilization to such an extent that it's just plain inviable.

You can work with metal via bio-processes, the scaly-foot snail is a nice example of this with its iron-sulfide coating its shell and the scales covering its foot, and you can harness the power of electricity biologically as is shown via the various electrogenic animals of our planet, but how long do you think a stone-age tribe will mess with the breeding of said animals into something more useful before they simply give up due to it seeming like it's not going anywhere(requiring generations of effort)? To say nothing about the fact that such a tribe will likely not even know that they'd be able to bio-engineer creatures via selective breeding. Yes, they might be able to notice that features of the parents are present in the offspring, and might be able to notice that the strongest among them produce stronger children(which carries truth in a society where training isn't really a thing, not so much in a society where most can afford some weights and know the benefits of training), and might try to apply that knowledge to themselves to increase the tribe's strength, but apart from extremely simple applications of said knowledge(which will also lead to crops and the like) the odds of them breeding the scaly-foot snails into bio-factories that produce swords and whatever else made of metal you'd need for a more advanced society is extremely slim.

Comment: Iron sulfide is not a metal, just like rust is not iron and clay is not aluminium.